# How to fertilize Azure mobile service Url with multiple conditions?

Tags: c#, json, web-services, azure, azure-web-app-service

How to fertilize Azure mobile service Url with multiple conditions
For Ex: https:///tables/todoitem?$filter=(id+eq+'123456789')
Here i gave only one condition how to pass multiple conditions.

i need data for both 2 id's like 123456789, 987654321. How to pass ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'and' and 'or' conditions like this:

```
/tables/mytable?$filter=id+eq+'1'+or+id+eq+'2'
```

If you have a lot of id's this might not perform as you want so be sure to test it.